# blazeds polling channel acting as session keep-alive

Tags: session, spring-security, blazeds, keep-alive

has any one faced this problem?

I set the session timeout to 1min, and it works fine.

But if i turn on a msg-polling channel with 5s interval, the session never expires. Is this expected? if so, how to disable this?

Using blazeDS 3.2, with spring security 3.0.5RELEASE and spring-flex 1.0.3.

TKS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the expected behavior, and you cannot change it unless you implement some custom mechanism. Like a timer in your Flex application, which will call a logout method on the server if an interval of time passed without any user interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it happen on the server-side, but I had to disable cookies on tomcat and a lot of other customizations on BlazeDS.

Comment: I´ll try this http://code.google.com/p/flexedtoolkit/source/browse/trunk/flexed-toolkit/src/flexed/utils/timeout/ClientIdleTimeOut.as